# codeigniter project without index.php file in root folder?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url, routes

I have got one codeigniter project which I tried in my machine and used it but after setting it up locally there are some issues like firstly it is not booted successfully and it lands on index.html page which is in root and showing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Directory access is forbidden.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

and this is my htaccess file

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all granted
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

what i am seeeing that there is no index.php file in root folder what does it mean , the developers who made this project may have done it purposely but my concern is how to run this project if i am not able to reach at its index point

I also tried to access it using proper url but then it shows

```
No direct script access allowed
```

because it gets stuck at this line

```
<?php 
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    if(isset($this->session->userdata['session_data']['id_client'])){
       $session_id = $this->session->userdata['session_data']['id_client'];
    }
?>
```

so I am not able to configure it properly

what i basically want to convey is how to run this project in my local machine and because of above issues i am not able to do so ...

so any help , or any ideas where i can look for ...

Comment: if you think they forgot to put `index.php` in root folder then just copy another `index.php` file to your root folder. But if you don't think it's their fault, just ask where they store the configuration

Comment: actually i dont have any reference of them and i have to start it by my own and the point you are saying i dont think they forgot to put index.php but i think they have slightly changed some configuration as it was running project .I just want to know what to look and what to check so that i can have some hints ..

Answer (score 0):

As per your htaccess file. I believe that problem is with your apache.

Please check if authz_core_module available in your apache.